# RecyclerView and NestedScrollView take only half of the screen

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-nestedscrollview

I have a layout where there is an `EditText` and `Button` on the bottom of the screen. I want the `NestedScrollView` along with the `RecyclerView` to take up the space above the 2 elements. However, they only take a part of it.

Here is my code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".HomeActivity">

    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/nestedScrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/etMessage"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:context=".HomeActivity">

            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/rvMessages"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true" />

    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etMessage"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Enter your message"
        android:inputType="text"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/btnSend"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnSend"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Send"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/etMessage" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: you might face some problems when your recyclerview is endless, like if you are calling any api while scrolling the recyclerview then there will be continuous api calls when the recyclerview is inside nested scroll view.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add this line in NestedScrollView

```
android:fillViewport="true"
```

Answer (score 0):

It will have the same height as your NestedScrollView has if RecyclerView has necessary amount of items in it. You can calculate necessary height of items.
And I aslo don't really think that you need NestedScrollView in your layout 'cause RecyclerView can be scrolled without it.